# How to iterate through members of a class

Tags: ruby, class, iterator

This:

```
class Loan
    def initialize(amount, interest)
        @amount = amount
        @interest = interest
    end
end

loan1 = Loan.new(100, 0.1)

Loan.each do |amount, interest|
    debt = debt + amount + (amount*interest)
end
```

won't work because it's attempting to iterate over a class rather than an array or hash. Is there a away to iterate over all of the instances of a class?

Answer (score 5):

Ruby doesn't automatically keep references to objects you create, it's your responsibility to write code that does. For example, when creating a new `Loan` instance you get an object. If you want an `each` method at the class level you'll need to track these by writing code that captures them:

```
class Loan
  def self.all
    # Lazy-initialize the collection to an empty array
    @all ||= [ ]
  end

  def self.each(&proc)
    @all.each(&proc)
  end

  def initialize(amount, interest)
    @amount = amount
    @interest = interest

    # Force-add this loan to the collection
    Loan.all << self
  end
end
```

You must manually retain these because otherwise the garbage collector will pick up and destroy any un-referenced objects when they fall out of scope.

Comment: In this particular case I would collect `debt` in the first place :)

Comment: @mudasobwa The next step is to make a proper ledger with credits and debits, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this: Add a few accessors for `amount` and `interest` then use the `ObjectSpace` object along with `inject` to sum up your debts.

```
class Loan
  attr_accessor :amount, :interest
    def initialize(amount, interest)
      @amount = amount
      @interest = interest
    end
end

loan1 = Loan.new(100, 0.1)
loan2 = Loan.new(200, 0.1)


debt = ObjectSpace.each_object(Loan).inject(0) { |sum, obj|
  sum + obj.amount + obj.amount * obj.interest
}

debt #=> 330.0
```

Comment: This has an undetermined result and is basically wrong. Try to put `sleep(10_000)` or [`GC.start`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/GC.html#method-c-start) or like in between of `loan2` creation and `debt` calculation. Even more, some smart ruby implementations might _never_ have `loan1` and `loan2` instantiated, since they never used later.

Comment: @mudasobwa For which Ruby implementation will this code not work?  The optimization you suggest (dead code pruning) isn't done by any Ruby that I know of, but more than that, I don't know how object creation, which can have side-effects, could ever be considered dead code.

Comment: @WayneConrad assigning the result of `Loan.new` to the local [not used anyhow] variable should not probably be considered a side effect, but I might be wrong. In general, even if right now there is no such implementation, it could easily evolve tomorrow and this code will all of sudden break. Better GC in ruby MRI might break this code tomorrow as well. This is unsafe and should be avoided, since there is _no promise_ in ruby specification, that created and not used objects will not be GC’ed forever.