# Ruby labeling printed outputs

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a short program that asks a user to enter a car model, maker, and year input and it passes that input through an algorithm. My question is, is there a way to label multiple printed outputs after it has been put through the formula to where it will number each output? Would I have to use a for each loop? I'm just trying to get a general idea of how I would accomplish this.

say for example the printed output would look like this.

```
class Car
    attr_reader :make, :model, :year
    def initialize
    end

    def set_make(make)
        @make = make
    end

    def set_model(model)
        @model = model
    end

    def set_year(year)
        @year = year
    end

    def get_make
        @make
    end

    def get_year
        @year
    end

    def get_model
        @model
    end
end


array_of_cars = Array.new

print "How many cars do you want to create? "
  num_cars = gets.to_i

for i in 1..num_cars
    puts
    print "Enter make for car #{i}: "
    make = gets.chomp

    print "Enter model for car #{i}: "
    model = gets.chomp

    print "Enter year of car #{i}: "
    year = gets.to_i

    c = Car.new

    c.set_make(make)
    c.set_model(model)
    c.set_year(year)

    array_of_cars << c
end

puts
puts "You have the following cars: "
puts
for car in array_of_cars
  puts "#{car.get_year} #{car.get_make} #{car.get_model}"
end
puts
```

1. 2014 Ford Expedition
2. 2017 Toyota 86
3. 2017 Aston Martin DB11

is there a way to add those numbers to the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead using a `for` loop you could try using `each_with_index`, which will allow you to get each element inside the `array_of_cars` and also the index for each element, in this case adding 1 to the current index will give you the value starting from 1:

```
array_of_cars.each_with_index do |car, index|
  puts "#{index + 1}. #{car.get_year} #{car.get_make} #{car.get_model}"
end
```

Or you can use `each` and `with_index` passing the first element, in this case 1 as argument:

```
array_of_cars.each.with_index(1) do |car, index|
  puts "#{index}. #{car.get_year} #{car.get_make} #{car.get_model}"
end
```

Comment: You're welcome, also for the `for i in 1..num_cars` part, you could also take a look to the [Ruby#Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so many methods. Use `attr_accessor` to set getters and setters and utilize `initialize` better. Then using the basic idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962038/5101493) by tadman, we can collect newly made objects into an array within the class itself. All together we can compress your class to:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :make, :model, :year

  def self.all
    @all ||= []
  end

  def initialize(make, model, year)
    @make  = make
    @model = model
    @year  = year
    Car.all << self
  end

end
```

We can use `times` to run a piece of code `n` times.

```
puts "How many cars do you want to create? "
n = gets.to_i

n.times.with_index(1) { |_,i|
  puts "Enter make for car #{i}"
  make = gets.chomp

  puts "Enter model for car #{i}: "
  model = gets.chomp

  puts "Enter year of car #{i}: "
  year = gets.to_i
  puts
  Car.new(make, model, year)
}
```

Then as Sebastián Palma has already suggested, use `each.with_index(1)` to print your cars. The argument offsets the index by 1.

```
Car.all.each.with_index(1) { |c, i| puts "#{i}. #{c.year} #{c.make} #{c.make}" }
```

---

<sup>Sidenotes: 1. Avoid using `for` loops in Ruby  2. Use `puts` not `print`.</sup>